# BindException cluster mode yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have 3 nodes cluster that through the UIs shows that everything is well connected. Now if i do submit a Spark application with deployment mode being cluster then i get : `java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind: Service 'sparkDriver' failed`. Full error in log (log of one of the Slaves) (when the application is launched on the current node then it runs well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should alter your code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().appName("sparkApp").master("yarn").getOrCreate();
```

You are using YARN (NOT standalone) you do not need to specify the driver.  Yarn does the assignment for you.

The [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) does say:

spark.driver.host: Hostname or IP address for the driver. This is used for communicating with the executors and the **standalone Master**.

Comment: That's also not required for yarn.

Comment: It feels like your following 'Standalone' example but you aren't running "Standalone" .  You are running on "YARN".  Maybe this will help you understand the different methods. https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-cluster-managers-tutorial/